# Moving files into subfolders (n files in each subfolder)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a little problem to resolve. I have a folder with a lot of files. I want it segregate it to subfolders in such a way that each subfolder contains a certain number of files. Eg. I have 1500 files and I want to move it inside to 15 subfolders (100 files in each folder) . Name of subfolders is wahtever it's not problem. I don t know how to use array to move it, I don't have idea for that.

I read a list of files from that folder and create an array like that:

```
string path = @"E:\test_folder";
string path2 = @"E:\test_folder\1";

string[] files_array = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

Then I can move files like that:

```
foreach (file in files_array){

     File.Move(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, file), System.IO.Path.Combine(path2, file));

}
```

But how I can create folder automatic and move only certain number of files and then create new folder etc. I try do this, but then I must refresh my array, so I think it's not a good idea.

```
while (files_array.Lenght > 0){

    foreach (file in files_array.Take(50)){

     File.Move(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, file), System.IO.Path.Combine(path2, file));
}
string[] files_array = Directory.GetFiles(path);}
```

I also think about write all array into txt temp file and then read it line by line and move files (then I wouldn't have to refresh array), but I don't know how do that. 
 What's the best solution for that?

Comment: You're familiar with `Take`. Are you familiar with `Skip`? `Take` 50. `Skip` 0.  Next iteration, `Take` 50. `Skip` 50. And so on.

Comment: @DanielMann, isn't this ineffective?

Comment: @vasily.sib: you can cache that. On 1500 items the perfor.ance impact is minimal

Comment: @Stefan, can you please show what do you mean by _"cache that"_. For 1500 items you will have 30 batches of 50 items and 22 500 meaninglessly iterated items.

Comment: Which would be executed in, let's say 400 ms - let's make it a second: an operation which is very small compared to the move of the files

Comment: @vasily.sib: that's why, it we speak of effectiveness,  we usually provide a context and we motivate why that that specific reasoning is valid. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to try to get all the file names in the folder and convert them into a string array and use a `for` loop

Try this code

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args){
      DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");//Assuming Test is your Folder
      FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files

      int tempCount = 0;
      string tempFolderName = "TestFolder";
      int tempCountFolder = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
      {
        if (tempCount <= 50){
          Files[i].MoveTo($@"{tempFolderName}{tempCountFolder}");
        } else {
          tempCount = 0;
          tempCountFolder += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you know how to move your files (with [File.Move(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8)), all you need is to iterate through array of filenames in batches. One way is to `Skip` / `Take`:

```
var i = 0;
var batchSize = 50;
var iterationsCount = files_array / batchSize + 1;

while (i < iterationsCount)
{
    var batch = files_array.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
    // do something with this batch...
}
```

But this is **totally** ineffective. You will run through part of your `files_array` in each loop without a reason.

---

Another way is to create an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` like this one:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> InBatches<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int batchSize)
    {
        var batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        var i = 0;

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            batch.Add(item);
            if (++i == batchSize)
            {
                // our batch is complete - yield return and create a new one
                yield return batch;
                batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        // something left in batch
        if (i != 0)
            yield return batch;
    }
}
```

Now you can use extension in this way:

```
foreach (var batch in files_array.InBatches(50))
{
    // do something with this batch...
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the term `totally`; and from the comments: I do wonder if skip actually itterates. Can you show the source?

Comment: @Stefan `Skip` and `Take` are not iterate your enumerable by them-self, but when **you** actualy iterate over results of `Skip(n).Take(m)` you at first [skip n items](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Skip.SizeOpt.cs) and then [take m items](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Take.SizeOpt.cs). It's OK for _Take(m)_ part, because you actually need this _m_ items, but _Skip(n)_ part is useless.

Comment: Also, if I multiple items count by N, `Skip` / `Take` will need N^2 more time. So if it were 400ms for 1 500 item - it will be 40s for 15 000 items and ~1h for 150 000 items.